# Why does cephadm keep saying Host is down

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ceph

I'm trying to set up a test instance of Ceph on my local machine (Windows 10, running in a wsl environment).

I've been following the [instuctions](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/install/#distribution-specific-installations) however when it comes to bootstrapping the cluster with the following:

```
sudo cephadm bootstrap --mon-ip 127.0.0.1
```

I get this:

```
Verifying podman|docker is present...
Verifying lvm2 is present...
Verifying time synchronization is in place...
No time sync service is running; checked for ['chrony.service', 'chronyd.service', 'systemd-timesyncd.service', 'ntpd.service', 'ntp.service', 'ntpsec.service']
Installing packages ['chrony']...
Enabling unit chrony.service
Non-zero exit code 1 from systemctl enable --now chrony.service
systemctl: stderr Synchronizing state of chrony.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
systemctl: stderr Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable chrony
systemctl: stderr System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
systemctl: stderr Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/cephadm", line 6242, in <module>
    r = args.func()
  File "/usr/sbin/cephadm", line 1451, in _default_image
    return func()
  File "/usr/sbin/cephadm", line 2883, in command_bootstrap
    command_prepare_host()
  File "/usr/sbin/cephadm", line 4574, in command_prepare_host
    check_time_sync(enabler=pkg)
  File "/usr/sbin/cephadm", line 4499, in check_time_sync
    if not check_units(units, enabler):
  File "/usr/sbin/cephadm", line 1725, in check_units
    enabler.enable_service(u)
  File "/usr/sbin/cephadm", line 4686, in enable_service
    call_throws(['systemctl', 'enable', '--now', service])
  File "/usr/sbin/cephadm", line 1112, in call_throws
    raise RuntimeError('Failed command: %s' % ' '.join(command))
RuntimeError: Failed command: systemctl enable --now chrony.service
```

Does `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.` have anything to do with the issue? If so what is `systemd` and how do I boot it from WSL?

If not can anyone point me towards what I need to set up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one of the [cephadm requirements](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/install/#requirements) is listed as Systemd.  Unfortunately, WSL doesn't support Systemd.  It uses its own `init` process as PID 1 instead, since it needs to initialize things differently due to the interop between Windows and WSL (networking, drive mounts, etc.).

While you can find methods of installing/enabling systemd on WSL, they are typically fairly buggy (by their admission -- I haven't tried it myself).  [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68874935/11810933) I've been meaning to try, though.  (Side Note -- Yes, it's on Stack Overflow, and really off-topic there, but it is too old to migrate. Thank you for moving yours over here instead.)  I do now know if this would be enough to satisfy `cephadm`'s requirements or not.

Also, while `cephadm` appears to be a fairly new convenience tool (and the recommended way to install now), you may be better off considering one of the [alternative installation methods](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/install/#other-methods) under WSL.  I also ran across [this guide](https://insujang.github.io/2020-11-03/deploying-a-ceph-development-environment-cluster/).

Comment: Or you try to deploy ceph in a virtual machine, that could make things easier for you.